# How to change IPython traceback mode with Qt event loop integration

Tags: python, pyqt, ipython

I can change the verbosity of the traceback in IPython using the `%xmode` [magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-gui). But this doesn't seem to affect the traceback when using GUI event loop integration. For example:

```
%gui qt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
button = QtGui.QPushButton('test')
def test():
    a = [1, 2]
    b = [3, 4]
    return a * b
button.clicked.connect(test)
button.show()
```

Upon clicking the button, the traceback looks mostly like the 'Plain' mode, and cycling through the different modes with `%xmode` doesn't do anything. How do I change the traceback mode to something like 'Verbose'?

Comment: PyQt is a wrapper around Qt written in C++. So maybe this affects the traceback abilities of IPython. Surely it can only traceback withing Python.